# How to compare more than two matched medians

Tags: r, median, paired-data, kruskal-wallis-test

My sample consists of 30 patients.
These patients had three times of hormonal dose measurement:
`Time 1`, `Time 2`, `Time 3`. So 3 three measurements.
The aim is to evaluate whether the average dose (in the blood) of hormone varies over time.
The distribution of the hormone dose is not normal. So I decided to do a non-parametric test.
Is the `Kruskal-Wallis` test the most appropriate? Can the `Kruskal-Wallis` test be applied to paired data?
I did some research on the `Kruskal-Wallis test`, but I found little literature on the analysis of paired data.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have an experiment arranged in unreplicated complete block design.  If so, traditional nonparametric tests are Friedman test and, maybe preferably, Quade test.  Here, *Patient* is the block and *Time* is the factor of interest.  You could also use aligned ranks transformation anova as a nonparametric test.

Any of these approaches have appropriate post-hoc procedures to determine which *Time* differs from which other *Time*.

As an aside, none of these approaches, nor the Kruskal-Wallis test, is generally a test of the medians.  If you were really interested in medians, you could use mixed-effects quantile regression.